# Using a wireless bridge for internet access while having an internal network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I have a situation which requires multiple devices to simulate an on-premise type install of a client-server setup. This I'm fairly certain can be achieved with a network switch (for more ports), a router (for DHCP and automatic IP address assignment) and some Ethernet cables.

The clients would also like to access the internet. Without using something like a 4G router, is it possible to use a wireless bridge connected to the WAN port on a router to add internet connectivity while letting the devices still communicate with eachother using the router-assigned IP addresses?

For context, this will be demoed at a show where public WiFi is available and we were hoping to add internet access to the clients should they want to connect to something other than the server.

I've attached a simple diagram of what I thought would be possible. The solid line represents a wired connection and the dashed line represents a wireless connection. Please note that the repeater is connected to the WAN port on the router.

[image: Network diagram]

The wireless bridge I am looking at in this example is here: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00AHXXJVW

If this was to work, how would something like the captive portal/login page be handled too? Would it require it on the first device to connect or all of them?

I'm not familiar with networking too well so sorry if I've made a load of bad assumptions.

Or even better, is there a way to achieve this in a better way?

Thanks, James

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work... the "public wifi" part may be limited to basic authentication like WEP/WPA/WPA2. The device works just like an access point, however you'd need to plug the bridge ethernet to the router WAN. You may have to do some configuration in relation to IP addresses.

Comment: The basic authentication part should be fine, I imagine it would have either that or be public. I also imagine that it would have some sort of captive portal which I'm not sure how would work. Plugging the bridge in to the WAN port on the router is the idea but what do you mean configuration in relation to IP addresses?

Comment: You would need to configure the access point to have an ethernet IP address so that you can configure the router WAN to have a same-subnet IP, so the two can talk to each other. Make sure the IP is not the same subnet as the LAN. You will need to test this theory.